# Implement auto-completion on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, autocomplete

**Scenario:** I have a list of medication (stored somewhere, let's say an NSArray).

There is a UITextField where a user can enter a medication to get more information about it (or whatever).

I want to suggest word completions while he is typing (but that is rather easy).

Where is the best place to show these suggestions? Since it's on the iPad i want it kinda like when you google and you get your suggestions right below the search bar. Is that possible on the iPad? A table that lays over the rest of the screen, placed below the text field? Like a pop up or something? I have never really used an iPad in my life before, therefore I don't know what the iOS way would be..

**Edit:** Something like this but connected to a textfield and not a button or whatever that thing is:

[image]

**Edit:** Or even better: Something like this but for iPad and not Android:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app I used a `UITableView` for displaying the suggestion.

I added the tableView above my `UITextField`. When there is no auto complete word found, I hide the tableView.

Please check my autocomplete implemetation.

[image: Auto Complete]

Comment: So you have to move the actual content depending on the number of results (well you don't do it yourself but at least it is done)? More results => Rest of the page is placed lower?

Comment: No, tableview is scrollable hence I didn't extend it. Also when typing more exact words the list gets the nearest value. Table is refreshed after each letter is typed.

Comment: but where exactly is the table? as an overlay? or whithin the actual view? do you have a screenshot?

Comment: @MarcMosby: In your image it's a popup with tableview

Comment: and this would be an acceptable  iOS way to do something like autocompletion?

Comment: but what if there is only 1 or none result? is there some blank space? it seems as if your application has to resize depending on the results, I want it on top to avoid blank space/resizing.

Comment: @MarcMosby: That's what I said if there is nothing I'm hiding the tableview

Comment: Sry but I can't imagine what that means (since I am neither an experienced iOS user nor developer). If the table is hidden, is there an empty spot the size of the table or is everything in your view moved towards the top?

Comment: @MarcMosby: It's an image from android app, you can use the similar thing, it is just placed the tableview below the textfield. You can use either option

Comment: You didn't quite answer my last question but I think I'm getting now what you are saying: It seems best to add a (dynamic) tableview below or above the UITextField. If there are entries to suggest fill the table view and set hidden to NO. (Since elements are placed in layers you can put multiple elements one above the other). **correct me if I'm wrong**

Answer (score 0):

Check out my control, [MLPAutoCompleteTextField](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mlpautocompletetextfield) for iOS. It is a subclass of UITextField that does autocomplete.

The implementation is similar to what you are looking for in the second screenshot, and very customizable.