# Implement a autocomplete textfield Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview, uitextfielddelegate

I am starting to work with `text fields`, and I want to implement a functionality with a custom autocomplete.

In a lot of blogs and answer, implement it with `UITables` to show the autocomplete, but I do not need this, I need to create a autocomplete like a iPhone function, where show a pop out with the filter but only with my array of words.

For example.

```
my_array = @{"apple","banana","pear","orange","berry"}
```

When I type "app" the text field only need to show me "apple" but not  complete the text in the `text field`, should show the pop up with the autocomplete.

Something like this but only with my array.

[image]

Comment: Check out https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it library complete the word in the textfield, and I need that the functionality suggest a word and the user decide if use it or not

Comment: The example you showed is the default Auto Correct that comes with iOS. I don't believe its customizable without violating Apple guideline.

Comment: so, do you think that is not possible create something like this ?

Comment: You'd have to implement your own logic and a UIView to display and things like that but it's certainly possible

Comment: I asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212933/implement-auto-completion-on-ipad. This might help you. Basic idea: TableView beneath your TextField that will be updated at each keystroke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build this behaviour yourself using the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods
( implement the delegate in your `UIView`

```
@interface someViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

In doing this you get access to whatever the user has typed in

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Where you can compare it to the items in your array and display another `UIView` or a custom button that when selected populates your text field.

Don't forget to tell your `textfield` who it's delegate should be, probably in your `viewDidLoad` method, but can also be done in the xib view

```
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

I know this seems laborious but it will be extremely gratifying. 
Here's the [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) for the `UITextViewDelegate`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, finally, create a custom UIView and I did all of functionalities in the method shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a custom auto complete textfield few days ago and the raywenderlich tutorial was helpful.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

You probably need to implement your own table view to make it look like the screen you attached. The short tutorial will give you an idea how it should be done. I will post my code tomorrow if you want.